# .htaccess rewrite query string not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have search and tried all possible solutions from Stackoverflow but nothing seems to work for my case.

I'm trying to rewrite this URL:
`http://www.example.com/test/name.php?name=somename`

to appear as
`http://www.example.com/test/somename`

This is what I have currently in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/?$ /test/name.php/?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Would appreciate if anyone can lend some help here as I have been stuck in this for more than a day. Thanks!

Comment: There's no regex placeholder after `test/…`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^test/?$ /test/name.php/?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
                  ^---- "0 or 1 of the previous"
```

Because you've got `^$` anchors in there, you're basically saying

```
/test/
/test
```

Are the only two URIs which could match. you probably want

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/name.php?name=$1
```

instead. "A url which starts with `test/`, and uses everything after `test/` for the name parameter".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RewriteBase!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . name.php?name=$1
```

Here "." is any request.

Comment: The OP is already using a root-relative substitution so `RewriteBase` is not actually required.